# Granting anonymous access only on a list when the site is configured to use Windows Auth?

Tags: wss-3.0, windows-authentication, anonymous-authentication

Is there a way I can grant anonymous access only to a specific list when the site is using Windows Auth?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! First you need to enable anon access for the site collection. Just enable it, you don't need to grant access to the entire site. Once enabled, go to your list and allow anon access to that one list. Accessing the list can only occur via it's full URL, users won't be able to access the home page.

HTH

David